# How can I upload video file while recording in jmeter?

Tags: java

I am using Jmeter2.12 in Linux fedora OS and recording using firefox37 browser.

In this environment setting, How can I Upload video file while recording in Jmeter?

Thanks,
Vairamuthu.

Comment: What do you mean by recording using Firefox? Jmeter is a standalone application... Do you just want to record your screen? Search Google for "Linux screen recording software" if you do.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter proxy is capable of recording file upload events, all you need is to put your video file under /bin folder of your JMeter installation.

See the relevant chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder (was: HTTP Proxy Server )](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) User Manual entry

> Uploading files
>
> Some browsers (e.g. Firefox and Opera) don't include the full name of a file when uploading files. This can cause the JMeter proxy server to fail. One solution is to ensure that any files to be uploaded are in the JMeter working directory, either by copying the files there or by starting JMeter in the directory containing the files.

For more information on simulating file upload and download events in your JMeter test check out [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article.

Comment: Thanks for your support.